# DnsPermission for executing Dns.GetHostName Method

Tags: c#, permissions, dns, msdn, hostname

I'm trying to invoke Dns.GetHostName().

Looking at the MSDN documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I see that the user requires **DnsPermission** 
for accessing DNS information. Associated enumeration: **PermissionState.Unrestricted**.

How can I grant/disable such a permission to some user?

Programmatically or otherwise. Thanks for the help.